# Eigenvalues of a matrix of complex numbers

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can a matrix of complex numbers  have real eigenvalues ? Imaginary part of the complex number are not equal to zero.

I know Hermitian matrix can have real eigenvalues, but what about non-Hermitian ones?

Comment: if this weren't possible, quantum mechanics would be in trouble! (in other words, see *the spectral theorem.*)

Answer (score 1):

Take for instance the matrix
$$
m =\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and conjugate it with a complex matrix; for instance, conjugate $m$ with
$$
t = \begin{bmatrix} 1+i & i\\2+i & i\end{bmatrix}
$$ to get
$$
t^{-1}  m  t =
\begin{bmatrix}3+i & i \\ -3+i & -i \end{bmatrix},
$$
which has still eigenvalues $1$ and $2$.